# With sed, using a regular expression, how to delete the special char ^?

Tags: regex, sed

Not being at all an expert with sed and regular expression, i would like to do this:

Deleting the char **^** in a .txt file like this:

if found **^** anywhere **delete it**, but if found **two or more times** like **^^** , **just delete** the first **^** so the result would be **^**

**For example:**

^example  -> example

^^example -> ^example

^^^example -> ^^example

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace a carret followed by 0 or more carrets by the carrets following it.

```
sed 's/\^\(\^*\)/\1/g'
#      ~~
#      |   ~~~
#      |    |
#    the    0 or more
#  caret    carets
```

Comment: If you used the `-r` flag, you do not need to escape the parentheses (or brackets, as some call them).